# Could you teach the context of the part of the sentence?

Tags: meaning

I came across the sentence

> "I have been looking for other work for a while now, but now that this
>   miserable excuse for a person as all but folded the school...well,
>   it's lucky I had a feeling and started looking for other job
>   opportunities when I did"

She left her job due to her stupid boss and she said the sentence. I couldn't understand "*that this miserable excuse for a person as all but folded the school...well*". Could you teach me?

Comment: That *as* appears to be a typo for *has*.

Comment: "miserable excuse for a person" is a way of expressing a low opinion of somebody. "as" in this context is probably a colloquial expression meaning "who has". "all but folded the school"?  no idea: maybe it implies that the boss didn't stay very long at school, ie is uneducated.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said in the comments section, there is most probably a typo, and the intended sentence was likely meant to be:

> "...that this miserable excuse for a person **has** all but folded the
>   school..."

Regarding the meaning of this, accoring to the following resource, the 'all but...' idiom has the following meanings:

> "Everyone or everything except those mentioned"

For example, you could say; "**All but** the weakest trees survived the storm". Another meaning is:

> "Almost, nearly"

Your own example illustrates this well; the person has *almost* (*all but*) folded the school.